# Passport expires 2 weeks before returning

Tags: germany

Traveling to Germany may 2018 returning may 17. 2018.  My German passport expires June 1,2018 I'm German citizen can I still travel???

Comment: Returning to where?

Comment: and what status, if any, you have to where you're returning (permanent residence, work visa, etc?)

Comment: In "many cases" you will be denied entry to a country if your passport expires less than N (often 6) months AFTER you plan to leave that country. You do not say where you are travelling from/to or whether you are travelling via one or more other countries. As phrased there is a high probability that you could not enter intermediate countries in either direction and a possibility that you may not be allowed to re-enter the country that you left from unless you have authority to do so that it not based on your German passport status. ...

Comment: Renewing your German passport **NOW** if at all possible seems like an extremely good idea. Telling us more will increase the prospects of us providing higher quality answers.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are entering Germany from outside the Schengen Area.

In most cases your passport must be valid for the entire time you will remain in Germany (thus in the Schengen Area). There is a passport control when both entering and exiting the Schengen Area and you cannot leave on an expired passport. As you are a German citizen, Bundespolizei will not care about the expiration of your passport in June when you are entering Germany, as there is no legal need for you to return to where you came from.

Some countries, however require that your passport is valid for at least X amount of time when you are entering or in your case are re-entering. You will have to make sure, you can return to the country you came from. Entering Germany will not be an issue.